# Uncaught TypeError: Net.createConnection is not a function

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, module, requirejs

I made an app in javascript, then i added NodeJS, then i wanted to store changes so i added mySQL database. 
the file made in NodeJS is working perfectly and taking the data from mySQL table and making array from it which i wanted to export using module.exports

when i added function Require i recived error "require is not defined'
then i added browserify to fix it
but i ended up with another error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Net.createConnection is not a function
at Connection.connect (bundle.js:27491)
at Object.239.mysql (bundle.js:35672)
at o (bundle.js:1)
at bundle.js:1
at Object.238../mysqlproba.js (bundle.js:35659)
at o (bundle.js:1)
at r (bundle.js:1)
at bundle.js:1
```

my whole app is here; https://megawrzuta.pl/download/124128207b1f55b9fbad42156ed5e191.html

u start it by writing
npm install
npm  start